# Creating a isomatricStagged Map with libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am learning creating a simple game with libgdx and already had some success. 
Now, i like to know the best way to use to create a simple isomatricStagged world.

Even with some camera troubles I have, I already implements a map, rendered, and use a cam.

What I want to know is, should I use Box2d and include my map to get boundaries? Or should I just render a 2 dimensional array for a map (this one is really slow after using more than 100x100 tiles).

thabnks for the rough overview or for some links to get these information. =)

opened on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140750/creating-a-isomatricstagged-map-with-libgdx as well)

Comment: You might be better served if you ask game related questions on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: thx Herr Derb. I ll forward it to this forum. =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with box 2D but an array should not be slow for just 100x100 tiles but you need to only draw what is needed unless your loop will draw thousands of off-screen assets. Calculating this for a staggered map is pretty straight forward:

```
Tiles X position in 2D array = worldX / tileWidth;
Tiles Y position in 2D array = worldY / (TileHeight / 2); // Since they overlap half on y axis.
```

So if that worldX/worldY would be the bottom left corner or center of your camera you can alter your draw loop to just draw what is on the screen. You calculate what tile would go in the top left corner and bottom right corner and iterate through.

```
Gridpoint topLeft; //Calculate based on camera position.
Gridpoint bottomRight; //Calculate based on camera position.

for (int y = bottomRight.y; y <= topLeft.y; y++)
{
  for (int x = topLeft.x; x <= bottomRight.x; x++)
  {
    drawTile[x,y];
  }
}
```

Now you are able to have a 1024x1024 map without hassle at all. But this does require a lot of memory since the large map array is stored. This is why you should only keep necessary data within a `Tile` object, like instead of a Texture a `int` referencing to a specific texture.

Comment: That's a good way to use an array. I haven't thought about it and I am going to try and compare it today with my current version. =) Regarding  box 2D, I can't evaluate really well which module/class I should use to have the best solution. Maybe box 2D is already outdated or something else should be better to create a isometric world. Furthermore, I like to figure out to use isometricStaggered map but still have trouble with the camera position. Thats why I thought to do sth wrong and should use something more than just isometricCamera, isomatricRenderignMap, Rendere and Batch.